# Scroll Div inside Absolute positioned parent

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

Im trying to allow the inner div in my HTML to allow scrolling. I'm not sure what is preventing the scrolling.

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class ="item item-text-wrap" ng-class="{show: showingdata, more: moreinfo}">
            <div>
                <!-- Stuff I don't want to have scroll -->
            </div>
            <div class="scrollable">
                    <!-- Scrollable Stuff Here -->
            </div>
</div>
```

And here's my CSS:

```
.item.item-text-wrap{
    z-index: 10;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    width:101%;
    max-height: 25px;
    color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    background-color: rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    border: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: max-height .1s;
    transition: max-height .1s;
}

.item.item-text-wrap.show{
    max-height: 180px;
    height: 500px;
}

.scrollable{
    height: 1000px;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 20px !important;
    overflow-y: scroll;

}
```

Note: In the past I've given the class .item.item-text-wrap a height value, although that has again not proved fruitful.

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No CSS expert here, but I think the trick is in the `max-height` of the parent div and the `height` of the inner div.

http://jsfiddle.net/60n26f25/

Answer (score 0):

Just use a  then you dont need a bunch of complicated css. if you dont want the top cut off add the class "has-header" to the parent div. Then you can click and drag to scroll the scrollable stuff

HTML:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0/css/ionic.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="app">
    <ion-pane>
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
        <h1 class="title">Awesome App</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>
      <div class ="item item-text-wrap" ng-class="{show: showingdata, more: moreinfo}">
            <div>
                <h1>stuff</h1>
            </div>
            <ion-scroll>
                    <h1>Scrollable stuff</h1>
            </ion-scroll>
</div>
    </ion-pane>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS: None

JS:

```
angular.module('app', ['ionic']);
```

See the Playground: http://play.ionic.io/app/f16c9cdc68bd

Comment: Thanks! Although when I scroll vertically and then let go of the screen it bounces back to the top of the scrollable content (I think the playground does the same thing). How would I fix that?